# Tor Doesn't Open after Initial install - Windows 10

Tags: windows

I haven't been able to get Tor v7.0.1 to run on my Windows 10, 64 bit system.  As has been mentioned in previous posts, Tor just doesn't open - no error messages, no nothing.  I have tried to download v5.5, but none of the links worked any longer.

Comment: Reboot windows into Safe Mode with Networking, then run it. If it works, there's some other software you've installed that is interfering with Tor Browser.

Comment: I installed TOR 7.0.1 on a USB and booted my Windows 10 64 PS (AMD) into safe node with Networking. TOR worked fine. I then booted into regular set up (I run MalwareBytes, SuperAntiSpyware, Windows Defender but not other "restrictive" packages. TOR did not start. I turned off the MalwareBytes, Windows Defender, and SuperAntiSpyware one at a time in that order and after each one stopped, I tried restarting TOR. I did not get TOR to start, So I gave up and went back to TOR 6.5.1. I'm not sure what software is interfering with TOR starting. It doesn't show up in the Task Manager even when It's tr

Comment: And in Safe Mode with Networking, as suggested? Often "stopping" antivirus isnt sufficient. Safe Mode with Networking is the best way to ensure it isn't loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am reading up on the safe start-up. Have been out of town quite a bit and haven't been able to devote any time to this. I tried disabling the antivirus without effect. I will look at that later this week. If I get tor to work in Safe Mode will it then work in Normal mode? Thanks again.

Comment: here is the reason I found in my case: EUS:Win32/CustomEnterpriseBlock!cl<br>
Alert level: Severe<br>
Category: Enterprise unwanted software.<br>
This file has been identified to pose a security issue and was blocked by your IT security administrator.

Comment: This may be a similar cause, but it doesn't actually provide a solution. Can you explain how you solved the problem?